# Java generics method signature explanation

Tags: java, generics

What does this generic method signature means

```
public <S, D> D map(S sourceObject, java.lang.Class<D> destinationClass);
```

I am referring to the `<S, D>`.
This method returns an object of the same type that was sent in the second parameter.

Can't I just write

```
public D map(S sourceObject, java.lang.Class<D> destinationClass);
```

Comment: What is the difference?

Comment: That's why *copy-paste* is dangerous.

Comment: Too much paste, not enough cut.

Comment: Let me guess, the second should read `public <D> D map(Object sourceObject, java.lang.Class<D> destinationClass);`. It's the same, type parameter `S` is not necessary.

Comment: Alright guys. Nothing to see here in the comments. edited the original question. and thanks.

Answer (score 19):

That means that this method invocation takes two type parameters: S and D.

The `<S, D>` part is meant as a declaration that this method is generic and takes two type parameters which are then used as placeholders for actual types in the method signature.

When you invoke the method, either you supply the parameters or they get inferred from the types of the expressions you are passing as arguments, like this:

```
String val = map(10, String.class);
```

In this case S is `Integer` and D is `String`

Comment: You need to explain more :(

Answer (score 4):

I guess there is still an error after correcting (or you should show us the whole class, if it also contains type parameters), but I guess I understood your question; as already stated in the comments, you can simply get rid of the `S` type parameter, because it's only used *once* in the method signature and replace it with `Object`. The reduced variant would then look like:

```
public <D> D map(Object sourceObject, java.lang.Class<D> destinationClass);
```

Answer (score 2):

`<S, D>` means that the method is generic (independent of class). Get parameters of type `S` and the class of `D` (`Class<D>`). And return the value of type `D` - independent of other types.