# Freestanding type parameter in Java Generics

Tags: java, generics, types, java-8

The type parameter section of Java generic types follows the generic class name.  For example:

```
class name<T1, T2, ..., Tn> { /* ... */ }
```

It's quite intuitive once you get a hang of it. However I am completely stumped to see some freestanding type parameter sections in the default interface methods of `Comparator<T>`.  For example:

```
default <U> Comparator<T> thenComparing(
        Function<? super T, ? extends U> keyExtractor,
        Comparator<? super U> keyComparator)
```

Clearly the method is returning some kind of comparator object, but how do you explain the freestanding `<U>` in English terms?

Comment: `U` is a method generic type parameter. In Java, not only classes might have generic type parameters, but methods might have them as well

Comment: ...and  to understand in detail https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html

Comment: The question is not whether or not methods can have generic type parameters (of course they do!), the question is about the freestanding type parameter.

Comment: The freestanding type parameter is precisely the method type parameter. That's the syntax in Java to declare generic type parameters to methods. You need to declare them somewhere, so that method arguments can have a generic type that is different to the generic types of the class.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21854077/java-generics-method-signature-explanation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It introduces the type parameter itself. If you were to write the method signature without it:

```
Comparator<T> thenComparing(
        Function<? super T, ? extends U> keyExtractor,
        Comparator<? super U> keyComparator)
```

that would mean, there should exist some concrete type named `U` visible to the method.